# Do you actually believe something or you think you believe something because you have accumulated?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, psychology, belief, human-nature

So what exactly is the dot line or a break point between knowing something and believing in something, level plus from basic philosophy.

When you think you believe in something, is that actually just our instinct telling you that you believe in that something on the basis of your own analysis of knowledge which you have accumulated through different sources?

Comment: The classical theory (Plato's) imposes two extra conditions on knowledge: the belief has to be justified (not necessarily consciously, but reliably, say, by a tested skill from long experience), and it has to be true (one need not know that, but, at least, should not be aware of evidence that puts it in doubt), see [SEP, Knowledge as Justified True Belief](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-analysis/#KnowJustTrueBeli). There are some subtle problems that show this to be insufficient, but that would be beyond level plus from basic.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.